# What is name of this design that looks like a chemistry molecule?

Tags: shapes, interface-design, terminology

I have to develop below design in Android. Before starting it, I should know the name of design so that I can search in Google to get some help.

Can anyone tell me what we say to below design/UI?

[image]

Comment: @Scott Do remember not everyone here is a native English speaker 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply call it a **Hexagon pattern/layout** or perhaps a **Honeycomb layout**.

Comment: Congrats on the 200k rep, Scott!

Comment: Thanks @ZachSaucier `:)`